# How to wait for multiple API calls from a Redux action creator?

Tags: javascript, promise, redux

Lets say I am calling a dispatch method in my actions :

```
return dispatch(add_data(data)).then(function(response){console.log("Done")}
```

and my `add_data` method looks like:

```
export function add_data(data){

  return (dispatch, getState) => {

    for(var i in data){
      var data = {'url': data[i]}
      return dispatch(myApi({url: "some_url", method: "POST", data: data,}
        )).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return response.json()
      }).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        return dispatch({response, type: types.ADD_DATA})
      })
    }
  }
}
```

It is working for only `first` data. Only `first` data is dispatched. It is inside loop and I expect it to `dispatch` for all the data from loop.

How can I achieve this ?

Thank you

Comment: `return dispatch(...)` returns from the function in the first iteration.

Comment: If I dont return dispatch it will not wait for function to complete and goes to another function.

Comment: I want this dispatch calling api for all the list value.. and then `then` method should be called.. any idea ?

Comment: I guess you are looking for [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).

Comment: Guess its doing the same like removing the return in dispatch.. Can answer with Promise.all

Comment: Maybe you shoul use `yield`?

Answer (score 5):

As soon as you `return`, The `return` statement exits the function. If you don’t want to return from a function in the middle of the loop, don’t `return` from it in the middle of the loop.

You can use `Promise.all(promises)` to create a promise that resolves when all the child promises have resolved. You can collect promises into an array as you create them, and later return `Promise.all(promises)` to represent them all:

```
export function add_data(data){
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    var promises = [];

    for (var key in data) {
      var itemData = {'url': data[key]}

      var promise = myApi({
        url: "some_url",
        method: "POST",
        data: itemData
      }).then(
        response => response.json()
      ).then(response => {
        dispatch({response, type: types.ADD_DATA})
      })

      promises.push(promise)
    }

    return Promise.all(promises)
  }
}
```